# Initialize parameter in recursive function in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, initialization

I wrote down simple algorithm for checking if Mersenne number is prime:

```
def is_prime_mers(result, step, modulo):
    if result != 0:
        if step == 0:
            return False
        result = result ** 2 - 2
        if result >= modulo:
            result %= modulo
        return is_prime_mers(result, step - 1, modulo)
    return True
```

Generally I don't need to give `result` parameter when script calls this function however I need it for recursive calls.

So only `result` need to be initialised for this function with value of **4**

I can write some initializing function like:

```
def is_prime_mers_init(step):
    is_prime_mers(4, step, count_mersenne(step))
```

But maybe there is some python/general programming pattern to do that in first function?

**Edit:** For all curious ones :)
This is function what implements Lucas-Lehmer test and checks if given Mersenne number is prime http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test - however I read only mathematic implementation - so this is purely my code solution.

`step` is number of recursive calls

`count_mersenne(step)` gives value of some Mersenne number: `2 ** step - 1` however I use some check in `count_mersenne(step)` because searching for prime Mersenne numbers can be limited to prime `step` values.

Comment: What is `count_mersenne` and `4`?

Comment: What would be the initial value of `step` and `result` be?

Comment: Initial value for `result` should be 4, step can be any, and basically   `count_mersenne` value depends on `step` and returns Mersenne number so this value is set outside, for performance reason I excluded this computation from base function. Updated question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign them dummy default values and then you can decide whether to change them or not, like this

```
def is_prime_mers(step, result = None, modulo = None):
    if result is None:
        result = 4                    # Default value
    if modulo is None:
        modulo = count_mersenne(step)  # Default value
```

Or in one liners

```
def is_prime_mers(step, result = None, modulo = None):
    result = 4 if result is None else result
    modulo = count_mersenne(step) if modulo is None else modulo
```

Comment: So how properly call this function `is_prime_mers(?,7,127)`?

Comment: @abrasadera That was what I was asking you, in my second comment in the question I guess. Could you please check that? :)

Comment: Grate thanx - If you can, just put to your answer example of this function called without self-initializing parameters - I'm new to Python so this is not explicit how it works:)